# I am having issue in my database table. Can anyone explain the highlighted error?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, database

I am an amateur in programming. I am trying to build a form, store in database and display the result of database.But, I am having issue in my database table. Can anyone explain the highlighted error? Thank You.

[image]

Comment: why you are not using any auto increament .

Comment: Your table have not a primay key  so each row is not editable by phpmyadmin (this is the meaning of message)..  you should change/recreate your tabel adding a primary key eg: a column name id with type int autoincrement

Comment: Could you please add the text of your error to your question? This is pretty much impossible to find by other developers in it's current state.

Comment: I think it is a little unclear what your error you are referring to because there are no errors in your image. You have circled your results table so can I assume you are referring to the gray lines? If so, this is because you have inserted zero length string into both columns so there is nothing for the HTML to show so all you get is a thin line. As others have suggested if you want to edit or delete the rows in PHPMyAdmin then it would be better to add a primary key to the table. You can delete those blank lines with  `DELETE FROM data WHERE name='' AND issues=''`

Comment: I think you're just having empty rows in your table. I would suggest to set "not null" in the fields that are mandatory. You should also have a primary key in your table, it works like an ID for each row, auto increment field should work. I would also take an online course on mysql, they're cheap on udemy e.g.

Comment: Why have you not created any primary key in your table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do few things:

- verify your table structure that you have auto increment `id` and mark as primary key
- further, if you need to add validation from where data is inserting that if name and issues are empty then no insertion
- moving next, you can update your query to `select * from data where name <> ''`

Let me know if you still didn't get your desired result